# What do these common C++ compiler flags do?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I'm a starter in C++. I'm still confused about the flags in my makefile.

```
-c. -o. -Wall. -g. -std=c++0x.
```

Can any one tell me what all these common flags do?

Comment: Your reading assignment for today: `man g++`.

Comment: They aren't even "C++ flags". They are specific to your compiler: `gcc`.

Comment: @Jongware: only the last one is very compiler-specific. the first three have been *de facto* standard since, well, early 1980s.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf if you don't know what you are using you can't even create the proper mental association between the software and the related docs. most of the time here on SO I just find people that are "assuming" stuff without even thinking about all the possible options and they don't even try to understand what the OP is trying to say. For example in this case the fact that the OP is talking about `g++` it's an "educated guess".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a replacement for publicly available product documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the last flag (compiler command option) is very compiler-specific. The first three or four have been *de facto* standard since, well, the early or mid 1980s, I think. Of course there’s no guarantee that any particular compiler will understand them, but they’re not uncommon.

Note: while Visual C++ accepts the `-` flag prefix notation, it is usually used with `/` as flag prefix, since that’s the common convention in Windows.

- **`-c`**
  Compile only, don't link.
- **`-o`**
  Specifies an output file, e.g. executable. Unfortunately deprecated
  for Visual C++ compiler. With Visual C++ use e.g. `/Fe`.
- **`-Wall`**
  With g++ all practical warnings. With Visual C++ all warnings including all sillywarnings, and that's a bunch!
- **`-g`**
  Generate debug information. Supported by many compilers but not Visual C++.

Then,

- **`-std=c++0x`**
  is a g++ compiler-specific option that specifies *sort of* C++11 standard. As I recall the difference from `-std=c++11`, for newer compiler versions that accept both, is that the former still permits some g++-specific language extensions.

Comment: You left out `-g`. On the Windows compiler I use, `-g` is "Stop batch compilation after n warnings (Default = 255)", and `-Wall` is an incorrect option.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: sorry, I didn't see the `g`. AFAIK it's not a common option. Which compiler are you using that doesn´t have `-Wall`?

Comment: bcc32 (blabla minimum comment size limit..)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: oh. that *sounds* like Borland C++ 5.0 from mid 90s? or is it something more modern from ... uh, I stopped following the history when Philippe Kahn stopped playing in the Borland band?

Comment: Latest ver is 6.70 (2013)

Comment: The '-g' option has been a *defacto* standard for including debug information into the object files or executable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: do you think I should put that in the answer? `-g` for debug info is supported by g++ (and so I presume also by clang), and e.g. by bcc and even by the archaic DigitalMars compiler, but not by Visual C++ (at least not the latest version). well OK noting a pattern here I'll just include it. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are not "c++ flags", those are flags for a compiler, presumably it's `g++` from the `gcc` suite.

All those flags are documented on both the online and the offline docs, the offline docs are probably easier to browse for a beginner due to the fact that you can just open the pdf in a viewer and use the search engine to search for a word.

[This are the manuals for `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).